# Auto updating cache with Spray-caching

Tags: scala, caching, spray

i'm really noob in scala and spray caching and i need to know how it work. 
i have db and i want cache some tables and update their every hour for exmaple. i can`t understand how it realise in spray-caching library. i think write something look like,

```
val cache: Cache[Double] = LruCache()
def cachedOp[T](key: T): Future[Double] = cache(key) {
//some big function which download table in json array
  getTableFromDb()
}
```

but have not any idea how it work. please help me, i want learn and understand. Sorry for stupid question and bad language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `timeToLive` property to configure your cache so it does not keep any entry longer than 1h.

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val cache: Cache[Double] = LruCache(timeToLive = 1 hour)
```

The value will be automatically evicted from the cache after 1h.

That means the next time it is accessed, it will not be found in the cache, so it will be computed and the result placed again in the cache for another 1h.

You are refreshing your cache by using it.

I would advise you to use as well the property `maxCapacity` to control the size of your cache so it does not grow out of proportion.

You could do something like :

```
val cache: Cache[Double] = LruCache(maxCapacity = 100, timeToLive = 1 hour)
def cachedOp[T](key: T): Future[Double] = cache(key) {
  getTableFromDb() // returns Future[Double]
}
```

Hope it helps.

see [documentation](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.1/spray-caching/)

Comment: Thanks, but i don`t know how it work? what happens after 1 hour? cache delete data or update it automatically? can you show me some example with work code?

Comment: I have edited my answer, tell me if it answers your questions.

Comment: thanks, you help me but i have some new questions. this decision for table look like as one object(in pair key-value? value is table), am i right? if i want cache(which is hashmap) with all rows  of this table(pairs key1-row1,key2-row2) what i should do? then i have many tables. i have just one idea about how organize it - cache with caches inside( look like key1-cachetable1,key2-cache-table2....) but it maybe bad and stupid idea. can you tell about this or give any advices and hints if you do not mind?

Comment: If you only want to cache db access, create one cache per table. Trying to cache different type of values in the same hashmap sounds like a bad idea IMHO.

Comment: i really stupid and i cant autoupdate cache. for exmaple i set ttl=5seconds and after this time row deleted from cache, not comuted again, just delete(

Comment: It is not updated automatically on deleted as I have written above. It just evicts the value. It is computed the next time you try to access it.

Comment: sorry if very stupid or don`t understand you. after 6 seconds of thread sleep i try to access cache - cache.get(key) and get none value.

Comment: don't use cache.get() as it only access the cache. Use you function "def cachedOp[T](key: T)" to access the cache as it execute the computation if necessary.

Comment: oh... but when using .get function is good way? maybe i don`t understand true behavior pattern for caching process... i see documentation and understand that def apply(key: Any)(expr: => V): Future[V] return value of my cache if exist and def get(key: Any): Option[Future[V]] return value of cache too

Comment: Read the code :) 
https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-caching/src/main/scala/spray/caching/LruCache.scala#L135
vs
https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-caching/src/main/scala/spray/caching/LruCache.scala#L120

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61261/discussion-between-mechanikos-and-arnaud-gourlay).